# bash: npm: command not found after installing nodejs on Linux

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, npm, npm-install

I want to install https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier .

But after using `npm install html-minifier` I get the message:

```
bash: npm: command not found
```

I'm using Debian 9 stretch and got nodejs by `apt-get install` .
I've tryed to fix my problem by installing nodejs-legacy and build-essential but nothing changed.
If I use `nodejs -v` I get `v4.8.2`.
I never used nodejs befor, what do I wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Try installing npm with 'sudo apt-get install npm' and it should work. You could also install node js via nvm (https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

It will automatically install npm for you.

Comment: Running sudo apt-get install npm gets me: 
`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package npm`

Comment: Can you try installing via NVM . Run 'curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.6/install.sh | bash' to install nvm. After nvm is installed you can then install node js by running 'nvm install v8.9.1'. After reloading .bashrc, the npm should work.

Comment: Now I have npm installed.
I'm very stupid npm doesn't belong to the official debian packes.
I installed it with:
`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -` and 
`sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`